# How do I find where my ZEND data is stored?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have inherited a system created on top of the Zend Framework. I am trying to figure out where the data is stored.

If this was a Code Igniter or Drupal implementation I would find the configuration file and likely see some MySQL database connection strings. And perhaps its the same in Zend as well but I am having no luck finding the file that would point to that.

Answer (score 0):

By default I believe there is a `configs` directory, which contains `application.ini`

You can start there for configuration settings.

For more info, check out the API docs: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.config.html